# What is the purpose of the scala.tools.nsc package?

Tags: scala

I've spent a good few hours googling for something to allow me to open Zip files in Scala (I know you can just use the Java API, but I was hoping to find a Scala friendly wrapper for it instead of faffing about writing Buffered/FileInputstream and so on)

So I was just messing about in the REPL and found this package

```
scala.tools.nsc.io.ZipArchive
```

Which after some digging and using this `scala.tools.nsc.io.File`, I managed to open a zip archive with all of the Scala niceness (being able to `foreach` etc)

The thing is I can't see any mention of this package in the official Scala 2.8.1 API document, so I was just wondering why there's no documentation on it? What is it?

Comment: This package is a part of the compiler api, not the standard library. You can always use the `java.util.zip` package.

Comment: Btw, `nsc` stands for new Scala compiler AFAIK.

Comment: I don't really like the way you use the `java.util.zip` though, you have to faff about writing boilerplate code just to open a zip file.
Whereas with this `tools.nsc.io.ZipArchive` package, for example I can write 

`val zipf = tools.nsc.io.ZipArchive.fromFile(tools.nsc.io.File("myzip.zip"))`

and get a pretty feature rich, scala friendly object to operate on!

Comment: @djhworld The scala compiler is open-source with a liberal license. You could take the source code for tools.nsc.io.ZipArchive and create a "third party" library for it yourself.

Comment: @axel22 OP explicitly mentioned already being aware of Java library solutions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this package contains Compiler-related classes. It's mainly used (as far as I know) for Plugin creation.

Due to it being related to Scala compiler, I'm not sure to which point it is a "stable" package and how much may it change between Scala versions, so be careful there.

Comment: thanks. I don't suppose you know of any Scala implementations that do something similar to what I want above? Like a third party library - I don't mind if it's just a wrapper for the standard `java.util.zip` package

Comment: Sorry but no, although if you find one post it! I will do the same :)