# How to write a value from the response to a file in Gatling?

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

I have a script which creates new referenceId each time its executed. I used

```
.check(regex("orders.(.*?)\"").saveAs("referenceId")))
```

to extract the referenceId. Now, how can I write/append it to a file without impacting the script even if I run it as a load test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used session in .exec to write my value into a file. Here it is:

```
.exec( session => {
                scala.tools.nsc.io.File("../user-files/data/refenceId.csv").appendAll(session("refenceId").as[String]+"\n")
                session}
      )
```

Answer (score 3):

You solution works, but...

First of all do not use anything (if you don't have to) from `scala.tools.nsc.io` package. It is internal package only for Scala compiler. It is not public API included in Scala runtime library (official Scaladoc). More about the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102396/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-scala-tools-nsc-package). Scala do not have any own abstraction for writing to file, hence one need to use normal `java.io.File` & co.

Secondly opening a file in each execution can (may not) slow down your load-test. It strongly depends on at which rate you are making the requests. At higher rates you can experience contention when more concurrent executions will be trying to write to same file. Simplest solution to this is to write to different files, but you can still run out of maximum possible number of opened files. Another solution is to use shared `java.io.FileOutputStream` resp. `java.io.FileWriter` to desired target file with proper synchronisation (will be accessed from various threads), which is still blocking IO. Yet another solution will be use Java NIO API to write to shared file via `Channel` (non-blocking) or `OutputStream` (not sure if non-blocking).

Of course solutions differ in difficulty of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

if this : scala.tools.nsc.io.File is not working try following....

```
.exec(session => {      scala.reflect.io.File("E://refenceId.csv").appendAll(session("responseBody").as[String] + "\n")
  session
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).